# PY - Compare several CSV file

Tags: python, csv, compare

I have several .csv files and some of them have more header and so more columns than others files.

I want to fill the missing columns into the files that don't have it

I tried this :

```
import os
import csv

# Get the directory where the Python script is located
script_directory = os.path.dirname(__file__)

# Define the folder containing the CSV files
folder_path = script_directory

# Get a list of CSV files in the folder
csv_files = [f for f in os.listdir(folder_path) if f.endswith(".csv")]

# Find the file with the most columns (maximum header length)
max_columns_file = max(csv_files, key=lambda file_name: len(next(csv.reader(open(os.path.join(folder_path, file_name), "r", newline=""), delimiter=";"))))

# Read the header from the file with the most columns
with open(os.path.join(folder_path, max_columns_file), "r", newline="") as file:
    header_to_copy = next(csv.reader(file, delimiter=";"))

# Iterate through each CSV file and copy the header
for file_name in csv_files:
    file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, file_name)
    data = []

    with open(file_path, "r", newline="") as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=";")
        for row in reader:
            data.append(row)

    # Update the header in the current file
    original_header = data[0]
    data[0] = header_to_copy

    # Print the differences between the original header and the copied header
    differences = set(original_header) ^ set(header_to_copy)
    print(f"Processed: {file_name}")
    print("Differences:")
    print("+----------------+----------------+")
    print("| Original Header | Copied Header  |")
    print("+----------------+----------------+")

    for item in differences:
        original_present = "Yes" if item in original_header else "No"
        copied_present = "Yes" if item in header_to_copy else "No"
        print(f"| {item:<16}| {original_present:<16}| {copied_present:<16}|")

    print("+----------------+----------------+")

    # Print the position of each element in the header if it was not in the original header
    position_dict = {element: position for position, element in enumerate(header_to_copy, start=1)}
    for element in differences:
        if element in header_to_copy:
            position = position_dict[element]
            print(f"Element '{element}' is at position {position} in the header.")

    # Add a new column with the value "0" from the second row onwards at the specified position
    for i in range(1, len(data)):
        for element in differences:
            if element in header_to_copy:
                position = position_dict[element]
                data[i].insert(position - 1, "0")

    # Write the modified data back to the CSV file
    with open(file_path, "w", newline="") as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=";")
        writer.writerows(data)
```

There is another example. I successfully found to use the position, but when there is a specific case it's not working :

Talbe1.csv
|a|b|c|d|e|f| g |
|-|-|-|-|-|-|---|
|1|2|3|5|6|7|888|

Table2.csv
|a|b|c|c (c)|d|e|f| g |
|-|-|-|-----|-|-|-|---|
|1|2|3|  4  |5|6|7|888|

Result:
Table1.csv
|a|b|c|c (c)|d|e|f| g |
|-|-|-|-----|-|-|-|---|
|1|2|3|  4  |5|6|7|888|

expected result :
Table1.csv
|a|b|c|c (c)|d|e|f| g |
|-|-|-|-----|-|-|-|---|
|1|2|3|  5  |0|6|7|888|

It's not working and i don't know why because i use the same position number

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest building a list of the headers in addition to tracking the file name, then you dont have to reopen the file and can use that list to build your output. When iterating over the files again simply use a `csv.DictReader` instead of a `csv.reader` and you can `row.get(header)` with default of `0` to build a list of elements for the row.  then write that row to the output for that file. You don't even need to keep the 'master' file open for this.

```py
headers_list = <the list of headers built during your first pass to find the longest number of headers>

for file in LIST_OF_FILES:
    if file != MAX_HEADER_FILE_NAME:
        data=list()
        data.append(headers)
        with open(os.join(folder_path, file), "r") as infile:
            mydata = list()
            csv.DictReader csv_file(infile)
            for row in csv_file:
                for header in headers:
                    mydata.append[row.get(header, 0)]
            data.append(mydata)
        //now open for writing as csv_write
        with open(os.join(folder_path, file), "w") as outfile:
            csv_writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=',')
            for row in data:
                csv_writer.writerow(row);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason not to use Pandas for this? It would be much faster /more efficient.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

#get file path
folder_path  = os.path.dirname(__file__)

#get list of files
csv_files = [f for f in os.listdir(folder_path) if f.endswith(".csv")]

#create empty df
df = pd.DataFrame()

#loop through each file and add it to empty df we created
for file in csv_files:
    dfx = pd.read_csv(file, delim=';')
    dfx['filename'] = file
    df = pd.concat([df, dfx]) 

#fill nulls with 0s
df = df.fillna(0)
#reset index
df = df.reset_index(drop=True).copy()

#split into component dataframes
for file in list(df['filename'].unique()):
    dfx = df.loc[df['filename'] == file].reset_index(drop=True).copy()
    dfx.to_csv(file, index=False)
```

Comment: i'm sorry but it's not working as i want 
I have a reference.csv file.
reference.csv
a;b;c;d;e;f;g
1;2;3;4;5;6;7

File1.csv
a;c;d;e;f
1;3;4;5;6

File2.csv
a;b;c;d
1;2;3;4

After your program the result should be:

File1.csv
a;b;c;d;e;f;g
1;0;3;4;5;6;0

File2.csv
a;b;c;d;e;f
1;2;3;4;0;0

Comment: You may have to sort the column names like this:`df = df[sorted(list(df.columns))]`